# Styling issue with Eclipse RCP app in Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, eclipse-rcp, macos-mojave

We build eclipse based product RCP product for Salesforce. It has been working fine in all OS and versions except in Mac OS Mojave where the styling of widgets looks whitewashed.

When we test the app in Mac OS Mojave from within the Eclipse IDE, the styling looks fine. However when we build the product and launch it, the background color of the widgets are whitewashed with dark border. Opening the same built product in Mac os other versions or in Windows, the background styling is fine.

Have you come across this issue in your Eclipse RCP app and Mojave styling issue? Or any thoughts or suggestions on what we could try?

From within the IDE in Mac OS Mojave:
[image: From within the IDE]

Opening built product in Mac OS Mojave:
[image: Opening built product in Mac OS Mojave]

Comment: Checkout this issue https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539660 . It looks similar to your issue

Comment: Assuming this is that bug you need to be using Eclipse 2018-12 or the current 2019-03 to get the fix.

Comment: Looks like that is the root cause. One issue with integrating with 2018-12 or 2019-03 is loss of Win 32 bit support. As of now, I found that 2018-09 being last version that supports Win32 bit.